# Java Comparable - custom compareTo consequences

Tags: java, comparable

I have a question regarding a specific overriding of compareTo.

```
class Sjavac {
static class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().toString();
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        return 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(A a : list){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
}
```

The result I get is that first A's string is printed, and then B's.

My question is, why is this the result? What exactly happends in this case?
When A is compared to B, it is considered bigger, and when B is compared to A it is considered bigger.
Than what determines that order?

Thanks

Comment: It breaks `Comparable`'s contract which requires a total order. If you had more than the two elements, chances are you would encounter an exception with a message to that effect.

Comment: Actually this was a Java exam question in my university.. (They asked what would be printed in this code)

Comment: Like @Heinrisch states, the result is undefined (due to the breaking of the contract), so the correct answer to "what will be printed" is "you can't say" or "it's implementation dependent". You're using `Collections.sort`, but you don't know it's implementation, and if you did, it might be subject to change between Java versions.

Comment: The sort implementation is said to be the Collections.sort

Comment: That's just the name of the implementation, you don't know it's mechanics. It could be implemented with BubbleSort or MergeSort for all you know, and those two will behave the same when the contract is fulfilled, but might behave differently in this situation - so you can't say. Again, it might even throw an exception (and probably should tbh).

Comment: The only correct answer is "*the behaviour is undefined*". If that is not the answer you were given, you should request that this question be removed from all students' results.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the result is undefined because you can't sort a list where the elements are changing. So, if you want to know why this is the result you have to check how the sorting algorithm works.

Comment: I am using the default Collections.sort algorithm

Comment: Then the result should be able to change if you switch to a different JDK. Just quickly checked the source code and it most likely uses insertion sort for so few elements, so it will only do one comparison and then conclude that the list is sorted.

Comment: Here is one JDK's implementation: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/DualPivotQuicksort.java#L107

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing B to A and return B should come after A (in B's compare to method). Also, you are comparing A with A and saying the first one should come after the second one (in A's compare to method). Then, you have a list with A object and B object. Sorting this, A is compared to B, B is greater (comes later), and that is returned.

The trick happened here, why do Collections.sort method choose B's implementation of compareTo? Because it's late binding! It's inheritance. Check this implementation, with console printing...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

class Sjavac {
static class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        System.out.println("A");
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().toString();
    }
}

static class B extends A {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        System.out.println("Here");
        return 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new A());
    list.add(new B());
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(A a : list){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
}
```